# Disable clicks on a NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview

I know that on a `NSWindow` you can use `setIgnoresMouseEvents:`.  However, a `NSView` doesn't have either `setEnabled:` or `setIgnoresMouseEvents:`.  Any fixes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement [the `hitTest:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/hitTest:) to return `nil`.